# How is it possible to have folders in object storage?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, object-storage, file-storage

As per my understanding, object storage has a 'flat' structure so you cannot create folders within buckets. However, in both GCP & AWS, I am able to upload regular folders to the buckets, which also look like regular folders on their web UI console. What is the difference between the folders I am seeing on these buckets, and the folders which are there in a file-storage system (like my personal laptop)?

Comment: In S3 the **console** _renders_ objects that have `/` in their key like a folder structure and you're also able to create special 0-bytes objects with a specific mimetype that the console _renders_ as folders. Under the hood and on the API level everything is key-value. The console just chooses to create a leaky abstraction that people are more familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Object Storage has a 'flat' structure so you cannot create folders within buckets, nor can you nest buckets in buckets.

If you need to have some form of 'folder'-like structure, then using prefixes is the way to go. You'll then end up with this structure: {endpoint}/{bucket-name}/{object-prefix}/{object-name}.

thats what you are seeing according to me